# Chart is not defined Node.js Chart.js

Tags: node.js, express, chart.js

I am begging you for help, I work on it all day and no solutions from the Internet work. My first Node.js application. Can someone help to solve the problem:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Chart is not defined
```

logic.js

```
var mychart = document.getElementById("radar-chart");
chart = new Chart(mychart, {
    type: 'radar',
    data: {
        labels: ['1', '2', '3', '4'],
        datasets: [{
            lable: 'Samples',
            data: [1,2,3,4],
            backgroundColor: ['#4e73df', '#1cc88a', '#36b9cc'],
            hoverBackgroundColor: ['#2e59d9', '#17a673', '#2c9faf'],
            hoverBorderColor: "rgba(234, 236, 244, 1)",
        }]
    }
})
```

pug

```
html
  head
    meta(charset='UTF-8')
    meta(name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0')
    script(src='/javascripts/logic.js')
    script(type='text/javascript' src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.9.3')
    link(rel='stylesheet' href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css')
    link(rel='shortcut icon' type='image/jpg' href='images/favicon.jpg')
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
    title Radar charts
  block content
```

I am asking for a solution

Greetings!

Comment: You have to include your JavaScript AFTER you import Chart.js

Answer (score 0):

You are loading your logic.js file before the chart.js script tag file, so chart.js isn't loaded yet but you try to acces it, if you switch it up like so it should work:

```
script(type='text/javascript' src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.9.3')    
script(src='/javascripts/logic.js')
```

Comment: "Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined" first and "Uncaught TypeError: Chart is not a constructor". I have this app without framework suppoer and it's working, this is the same code....

Comment: I switched scripts and changed script to: <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>.  Now i have: : "Failed to create chart: can't acquire context from the given item" I found that i need to add ".getContext('2d')" and now i have "document.getElementById(...) is null" xD

Comment: It can't acquire the context so it almost sounds like the js is running before the html is fully loaded, try wrapping your js functions in a window.onload so it will run after your page is fully loaded: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event